# If statements in masm: Syntax error in control flow directive

Tags: masm

I am trying to use the `if` macro in MASM, but I keep getting the following error message from the MASM assembler: `Syntax error in control flow directive.` I'm still not sure what the syntax error is here: what is the correct syntax for if statements in MASM?

```
.686p
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 2048

.data
X   byte         1;

ExitProcess proto, exitcode:dword 

.code
start:

.IF(x > 1): ; "syntax error in control-flow directive"
    mov ah, x;
.ENDIF

invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the colon ":" after ).  Also, you define X as a capital letter, but use the lowercase x, this is not valid.  Assembly is case sensitive.